# SQL Server 2005 Replication

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2005, replication

Environment:
SQL Server 2005 SP2 (9.0.3077)
Transactional Publications (Production and Beta)

I have a situation where I have two different Replication Publications setup that use some of the same Articles.  Each of these Publications feeds a subscriber on a different machine.  One of these shared Articles is a table.  At a regular time interval many of the records in this table become aged and no longer needed.  At this time a stored procedure that deletes records is called.

To save on resources and improve latency times to the subscribers I have set the replicate property on this stored procedure to “Execution of the stored procedure” instead of the default “Stored procedure definition only”.  This way when the stored procedure deletes 2,000,000+ records these don’t replicate down to the subscribers.  Instead the execution of the stored procedure is replicated and the same replicated stored procedure on the subscribers is executed and it deletes the same 2,000,000+ rows.

The problem I’m having is with my second publication.  I didn’t need this type of behavior so I left the article property on the stored procedure set to “Stored procedure definition only” and was expecting replication to remove the rows at the other subscriber but it wasn’t.  The table at the subscriber just kept gaining records. So to fix it I set the Article Property to "Execution..." and called it good.  Which is probably the best solution so beta matches production, but it still feels like a kludge as the publication properties should work independently of each other.

Question: Why does the “Execution of the stored procedure” article property take precedence and get applied to the other publication even though it is set to “Stored procedure definition only” in the other publication?

Comment: Not wanting to play Stackoverlfow down here however this question is quite an advanced SQL Server Replication query. I would suggest posting it on the Microsoft SQL Server Replication Forum and then subsequently update this post with the resutls.

Comment: While I am working on some replication stuff right now as well, I agree with John. This is a pretty tough question. Good luck. :) Might have to wait until someone makes querytimeout.com

Comment: Agreed, Hillary Cotter is a well known replication expert & watches the sql server replication forum http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreplication

Comment: Try ServerFault.com. Anyone can access it now with the password "alt.sysadmin.recovery"

Comment: I'm accepting this as working as intended and consider this to be an undocumented feature of Microsoft SQL SErver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use replication extensively in our company as we have 38 warehouses in several countries all replicating back to our primary server in London.

Firstly, your replication filters should use Views, even the simple ones. That way, if you need to adjust the filter (read WHERE clause), you just need to alter the view and your done. Otherwise you have to re-publish your data, and re-subscribe everyone which can be a real pain.

You mentioned that you run the same delete on both subscriber and publisher to keep them in-sync. This sends shivers down my spine. Your far better off deleting them in one place and letting the server replicate out to the subscribers the changes made. Since SQL Server 2005, replication is very fast and efficient now. SQL 2000 was and is quite slow for replication. If your using SQL 2005/2008, just make sure your compatibility level (right click on db, properties, options) is set to 90 (2005) or 100 (2008). This switches sql server over to the fast and efficient replication methods.

Another way is to not delete the data, but to keep it and filter it out using a where clause in the publication.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a long time since I actively administered replication but I suspect the answer has to do with the architecture of the log-reader and that you are sharing an article between publications. My understanding is that the log-reader will trawl through the log and look for operations on items that are replicated. Depending on the article settings, the individual changes to the data may be posted to a table in the distribution database or a record of the procedure invocation will be posted. In any case, this is a property of the article and not the publication(s) that the article is a member of. I assume (but have not tested and verified) that you can create multiple articles on top of the same database object and have one be replicated with @type='logbased' and the other with @type='proc exec'

Take all of this with a large pinch of salt: although I now develop on SQL 2008, the last time I did anything with replication was SQL 7.

pjjH